# Simulating the Value-at-Risk with $t$ distributed returns

Tags: time-series, value-at-risk, simulations, quantmod

I want to understand how the value at risk and the simulating the VaR with simple Monte Carlo method. But I want just a confirmation and are welcome any comments, since I don't have the full picture of this calculations.

Let's say that I have an annual asset with one period of margin risk:

```
library(quantmod) 
getSymbols("WILL5000IND",src="FRED") 
wilsh <- na.omit(WILL5000IND)
wilsh <- wilsh["2016-01-01/2016-12-31"] 
names(wilsh) <- "TR"
y = wilsh
n=length(y)
logret <- diff(log(wilsh))[-1]
```

Now I calculate the empirical VaR with $\alpha = 0.05$

```
alpha <- 0.05
rvec <- as.vector(logret)
quantile(rvec,alpha)
```

With result:

```
        5% 
-0.01253343
```

Fitting the data in a $t$-distribution and calculate through maximum likelihood method the parameters are:

```
t.fit <- fitdistr(rvec, "t")
round(t.fit$estimate,6)
mu = t.fit$estimate[1]
sd = t.fit$estimate[2]
df = t.fit$estimate[3]
```

Now the value at risk of the $t$-distributed returns is

```
q = qt(alpha,df=df)
varfit = as.numeric(mu + sd *sqrt((n-2)/n)*q)
varfit
```

with result:

```
-0.01183847
```

now if I am so far right, I want to simulate the value at risk for one day ahead so I am doing:

```
rvecs <- rep(0,100000) 
library(metRology)
for (i in 1:2) {
  rvecs <- rvecs+rt.scaled(100000,
                         mean=t.fit$estimate[1],
                     sd=t.fit$estimate[2],
                         df=t.fit$estimate[3]) }

VaRsim =  quantile(rvecs,alpha);VaRsim
```

With result:

```
        5% 
-0.01659703
```

I don't know if my simulation is correct since the result (from Monte Carlo is not exactly the same). Also I don't know if my methodology is correct.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From your statement,**

> now if I am so far right, I want to simulate the value at risk **for one day ahead** so I am doing:

**it looks like you want to forecast Value-at-Risk** and not just estimate it from the simulation of a Students t-distribution. If you want to forecast your parametric Monte Carlo VaR, you can follow the framework described below.

**In general**, I am confused about your for-loop, since it seems redundant. If you want to verify that you have done your calculations correctly and thus re-simulate returns from a scaled $t$-distribution using `rt.scaled`, you need to simulate much more samples, try around 2 million samples.

---

### Forecasting parametric Monte Carlo VaR:

The idea of forecasting parametric Monte Carlo VaR on the basis of a model $f(\theta)$, lies in simulating a large sample of returns (*or log-losses*) from the "forecasted" model, $f(\theta_{t\vert t-1})$ and then estimate the $\alpha$-quantile on your simulated data. Here $\theta_{t\vert t-1}$ denotes the conditional parameters for time $t$ given the information available at time $t-1$ and is (*generally*) the only thing that recursively changes from day to day. A general framework is described below.

#### Framework:

**1.** Convert your price-series to log-returns (*or log-losses*).

**2.** From this, estimate the model parameters $\theta_{t\vert t-1}$ using the information available today (aka. $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$) via eg. a moving window or an expanding window. Examples are given below:

- **Moving window:** With a window length of 1000 and a log-return series of $r_1,\ldots, r_{2000}$, use the first 1000 data-points to estimate $\hat{\theta}_{1001 \vert 1000}$ and use the estimated parameters in your model, $f(\hat{\theta}_{1001 \vert 1000})$, to simulate a large sample of log-returns. At time $t=1001$, estimate the parameters from the series $\{r_2,\ldots,r_{1001}\}$ thus keeping the window length fixed and use these parameters to simulate a large sample of log-returns. This is done recursively.
- **Expanding window:** Follows almost the same idea as a **moving window** instead of fixing the window-length, we just increase it gradually: for time $t=1000$ estimate from $\{r_1,\ldots,r_{1000}\}$, for $t=1001$ do $\{r_1,\ldots, r_{1001}\}$ and so on.

**3.** For each day, find the one-day ahead $VaR_{t\vert t-1}(\alpha)$ forecast as the $\alpha$-quantile **on the simulated data**, ie. $VaR_{t\vert t-1}(\alpha) = F^{-1}_\alpha(\theta_{t \vert t-1})$. In your case, $F^{-1}_\alpha(\mu_{t \vert t-1}, \sigma_{t\vert t-1})$ is the quantile function of a Student's t distribution, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ denotes respectively the scale and location parameter.

---

**If you want to assess the out-of-sample VaR performance**, you can use Failure rates or the unconditional and conditional coverage tests (*see for instance the forecasting section of [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/jfec/article-abstract/8/1/29/862829?login=false)*).

### Code illustration for moving and expanding window:

**The code below illustrates the moving and expanding window**. Within both for-loops we estimate the parameters of the Students' t-distribution, where the first for-loop (*the moving window*) keeps the window length fixed at 500 and the latter (*the expanding window*) increases the window length by 1 for each iteration. I encourage you to look it through and get a feel for how it works. **I hope it helps.**

```
#your own code, extended data from 2016 till 2019
library(quantmod) 
getSymbols("WILL5000IND",src="FRED") 
wilsh <- na.omit(WILL5000IND)
wilsh <- wilsh["2016-01-01/2019-12-31"] 
n=length(wilsh)
logret <- diff(log(wilsh))[-1] * 100

#initialize window length and matrices:
win_length <- 500
est_pars_moving <- matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = n - window_length)
est_pars_expanding <- matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = n - window_length)

#Moving window estimation:
for(i in (win_length+1):n){

  est_pars_moving[(i-win_length), ]<-fitdistr(rvec[(i- win_length):(i-1)], "t")$estimate

}

#Expanding window estimation:
for(i in (win_length+1):n){

  est_pars_expanding[(i-win_length), ] <- fitdistr(rvec[1:(i-1)], "t")$estimate

}
```

Comment: Your answer is very clear and helpful.Can you demonstrate these two (moving and expanding) windons estimations in R in order to have a better understanding how this is being implemented?

Comment: @HungryHomer I have added an additional section illustrating the moving and expanding window in `R`. It is up to yourself to build upon the code and the above framework in order to obtain the VaR forecasts.

Comment: In order to obtain the VaR in the forecast I can just code ``` quantile(est_pars_moving ,alpha)```? It seems like you are doing a backtesting like estimation to the Monte Carlo model.Am I right ?

Comment: The output is a matrix with 3 columns for each parameter of $t$ distribution.If I take the mean of each column  ```l=apply(est_pars_moving,2,mean)``` and find the 0.01 quantile of t: ```qt(0.01,l[3])```

Comment: @HungryHomer Backtesting is a process of comparing the forecasted/predicted VaR estimates to the realized losses experienced in the test-set (out of sample set). Failure rates and coverage tests are part of backtesting a VaR framework. Thus, forecasting VaR is just one part of backtesting (the other being the comparison of the realized values). The above code estimates the parameters for the $t$-distribution. For each of these parameters you need to simulate a large sample of returns and then calculate the $\alpha$-quantile on the simulated data and not take quantile of the parameters itself.

Comment: Hi @HungryHomer, I missed your last comment, so I'll give a brief answer here. Yes you can insert the estimated parameters into the quantile function of the $t$-distribution and back out your VaR forecast (there's essentially no reason to perform a simulation scheme). Monte Carlo VaR is usually done when the quantile function of the underlying distribution is not readily available (might be very hard to numerically compute or complex to program due to your assumed models complexity), therefore you can opt to a Monte Carlo Scheme to recover your VaR forecasts as described above [1/2].

Comment: 2. Also, you insert the set of parameters 1 by 1 in the quantile function and thus you should not take any mean. Understand that these are forecasts you get for each day: at day 500 you have 500 days of data and decide to use it to get a forecast for tomorrows VaR. You estimate the parameters (1st row in the output of the for-loop) and calculate your VaR forecast. Tomorrow at day 501, you want to do the same and get VaR forecast for day 502. Therefore you estimate your parameters from day [2,...,501] (2nd row in output) and use them to get a VaR forecast for day 502. This continues on. [2/2]

Comment: Someone can use these moving and expanding for loops to backtest a risk or marginal function.In a matter of speech I think that the expanding version is something like conditional forecasting t+1?Or I missed it?

Comment: @HungryHomer Yes. The window methods are applicable in a general point forecasting situation (eg. volatility forecasting or Macroeconomical forecasting). Both methods are conditional forecasting. Expanding window uses all information available (from $t=1$) and adds 1 more data point each day. The downside of expanding window is the fact that more data tend to stabilize your estimates "too much". Moving window fixates the window length and only uses the past eg. 500 days of data. This will make your estimates more sensitive to recent data.